# Instanciate a generic class

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, instance

Code:

```
class MyClass<T>{
    public void method(){
        new ArrayList<T>();//OK- Why?
    }
}
```

Why in this case we've not a compile error. Type `T` doesn't match to a specific type at compile time.

Comment: Please go through the [official `Generics` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an instance of `MyClass`, you will have to provide the type `T`. So, when call `method`, type `T` will be bound to whatever type `T` was defined in the construction of `MyClass`.

Comment: Thanks!!! But if i tried to add static modifier to `method` i have compile error. Why its occuring?

Comment: Because T is defined when you create the instance. The static method exists without an instance.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, Java compiler does not need to know the exact type of T to generate code. It turns all generic types to Object in the process called erasure.

Of course, at compile time it checks whether the program is "type-correct". In this case it is, because T is just a parameter given to the class at its construction. So when you call `new ArrayList<T>` the type `ArrayList<T>` is defined because type T it is considered as known.

Answer (score 0):

You're instantiating an `ArrayList`, not a `T`.
Javac can know that `ArrayList` has a default constructor with no parameters at compile time, so there is no problem.